# collapse and expand in pageblosection when loading the page

Tags: apex, visualforce

When i click the below command link, page block section should be open , if anything pageblock section open, it will be close.

Could you tell me the answer?

Code :

```
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="{!modelvalue}__Qty={!a.Quantity} | Total Hours={!a.totalHours} | Sell Price=${!a.tatolprice}" id="section1" collapsible="true"> 

                     <!-- <script>twistSection(document.getElementById("{!$Component.section1}").childNodes[0].childNodes[0]); </script> -->

<script>twistSection(document.getElementById("{!$Component.section1}").childNodes[0].childNodes[0]); </script>

                         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!a.wrapTaskList}" var="val" id="table">
                             <apex:column headerValue="Select">                    
                             <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!val.Select__c}"/>
                             <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" rerender="addquoteform" status="topStatus" action="{!totalcal}"/>
                             <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="addquoteform" status="topStatus" action="{!totalcal}"/>
                           </apex:column>

                         <!--<apex:column >                    
                             <apex:outputtext value="{!IF(val.checkbox__c,True,False)}"/>
                         </apex:column> -->

                         <apex:column headerValue="Task">                    
                             <apex:outputText value="{!val.Name}"/>
                            <!-- <apex:facet name="footer"> 
                             <b>Total:</b></apex:facet>     -->                        
                         </apex:column>
                         <apex:column headerValue="Qty">                    
                             <apex:outputText value="{!a.Quantity}" rendered="{!val.Select__c}"/>
                             <!-- <apex:facet name="footer"> 
                             <apex:outputText value="{!Quantity}" />
                             </apex:facet> -->
                         </apex:column>    
                         <apex:column headerValue="Hrs/Chiller">                    
                             <apex:outputText value="{!val.Hours__c}" rendered="{!val.Select__c}"/>
                            <!--  <apex:facet name="footer"> 
                             <apex:outputText value="{!a.totalHours}" />
                             </apex:facet> -->
                             <!--  <apex:outputText value="" rendered="{!NOT(val.checkbox__c)}"/> -->
                         </apex:column>

                         <!-- <apex:column headerValue="Sell">                    
                             <apex:outputText value="{!val.Sell__c}" rendered="{!val.Select__c}"/>
                         </apex:column> -->

                         <apex:column headerValue="Sell Price" rendered="{!val.Select__c}">  
                          <apex:outputText value="${0,number,###,###,###,##0.00}"
                                style="float:right;">
                                <apex:param value="{!val.Sell_Price__c}" />
                            </apex:outputText>                   
                             <!-- <apex:outputText value="${!val.Sell_Price__c}"/> -->
                             <!--<apex:facet name="footer"> 
                             <b>Total:</b><apex:outputText value="${!a.tatolprice}" /></apex:facet> -->
                         </apex:column>


                         </apex:pageBlockTable>        




                      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!a}"  var="val1" id="table1"> 
                      <apex:column >                    
                             <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!val1.refselect}"/>
                             <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" rerender="addquoteform" status="topStatus" action="{!totalcal}"/>
                             <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="addquoteform" status="topStatus" action="{!totalcal}"/>
                         </apex:column>
                          <apex:column >                    
                             <apex:outputText value="Labor to charge refrigerant"/>                                                     
                             <!--  <apex:facet name="footer"> 
                             <b>Total:</b></apex:facet>    --> 
                         </apex:column>
                          <apex:column >       
                           <apex:outputText value="Enter Qty of 125lb Cylinders" style="float:right;">

                            </apex:outputText>               
                            <!--  <apex:outputText value="Enter Qty of 125lbs Cylinders"/>     -->                                                
                             <!-- <apex:facet name="footer"> 
                             <b>
                             <apex:outputText value="Total:" style="float:right;">
                              </apex:outputText> 
                             </b></apex:facet>    --> 
                         </apex:column>
                         <apex:column >                    
                             <apex:inputText value="{!a.refnumber}" size="1" rendered="{!val1.refselect}"/>
                          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="addquoteform" status="topStatus" action="{!totalcal}"/>
                       &nbsp;
                       <apex:commandLink action="{!totalcal}" styleClass="URLStyle"  style="color:blue" rendered="{!val1.refselect}"
                            rerender="addquoteform" >Recalc</apex:commandLink> 

                            </apex:column>

                             <apex:column >
                              <apex:outputText value="{0,number,###,###,###,##0.00}" rendered="{!val1.refselect}"
                                style="float:left;">
                                <apex:param value="{!a.reftotal}" />
                            </apex:outputText>   

                             <apex:facet name="footer"> 
                             <apex:outputText value="Total:" style="float:right;"/>
                             </apex:facet> 
                             </apex:column>  

                           <!--<apex:column > 
                          <apex:outputText value="{!reftotal}" rendered="{!val1.refselect}"/> 
                            <apex:facet name="footer"> 
                             <apex:outputText value="{!a.totalHours}" />
                             </apex:facet>
                           </apex:column>  -->

                         <apex:column >    
                          <apex:outputText value="${0,number,###,###,###,##0.00}" rendered="{!val1.refselect}"
                                style="float:right;">
                                <apex:param value="{!a.refsellprice}" />
                            </apex:outputText>                
                             <!-- <apex:outputText value="{!refsellprice}" rendered="{!val1.refselect}"/> -->
                            <!-- <apex:outputText value="{!refnumber*0.925}" rendered="{!val1.refselect}"/> -->
                             <apex:facet name="footer"> 
                             <b>Total:</b><apex:outputText value="${0,number,###,###,###,##0.00}" style="float:right;">
                             <apex:param value="{!a.tatolprice}" />

                             <!--<apex:param value="{!tatolprice+a.refsellprice}" />-->

                             </apex:outputText> 
                             </apex:facet> 
                          </apex:column>       
                       </apex:pageBlockTable> 


                     </apex:pageBlockSection>


                        <!-- <apex:panelGrid headerClass="Name" id="pgr"> 
                               <Center>
                            <b>Total Sell Price:</b><apex:outputText value="{!a.tatolprice}"/>
                            </Center>                   
                        </apex:panelGrid> -->
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>

                   </apex:repeat>      




<apex:commandLink action="{!Add}" styleClass="URLStyle"  style="color:blue" 
                        rerender="addquoteform"  >Add Chiller <script> </apex:commandLink>

            </apex:pageblock>
```

Comment: There are two apex:commandLink; which one is your question about?

Comment: Add Chiller link, it is the last of the code